# I am trying to calculate a certain number with C++ for loops, but I keep getting the "Program has stopped working" Error message

Tags: c++, math, eulers-number

I am trying to run this code in Dev C++:

```
    #include<conio.h>
    #include<iostream>


    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        float sum =1;
        int num = -1;

        for(int i=1; i<=1000; i++)
        {
            num *= i;
            sum += 1/(num);
        }
        cout<<sum<<endl;
        getch();
        return 0;
    }
```

Whenever I compile and run the code, I get the Windows error message that the program has stopped working.  Could someone please help me?

With this code, i am trying to calculate the following summation:

∞

∑  1/n!

n=0

Comment: When you get "program has stopped running", it's time to run your program with the _debugger_.

Answer (score 7):

(The lower limit of your sum ought to be 1 not 0, but let's set that aside.)

Your algorithm is so numerically unstable that no repairs will make it work effectively. Simply put, factorials just get too big. The behaviour on overflowing an signed integral type other than `signed char` or `char` is undefined. What seems to be happening is that `int` is essentially taking the factorial modulo a large power of 2, and eventually that will be 0 since large factorials are multiples of large powers of 2. So a division by 0 occurs yielding the behaviour that you observe.

Fortunately you might notice that your sum can be written as

```
1 + 1/2(1 + 1/3(1 + 1/4...))
```

which is much simpler to chomp through numerically. One approach would be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
int main() {
    constexpr int N = 19;
    double sum = 1 + 1.0 / N;
    for (int n = N - 1; n >= 1; --n){
        sum = 1 + sum / n;
    }
    std::cout << std::setprecision(15) << sum << " " << std::exp(1);
}
```

The output `2.71828182845905 2.71828182845905` is obtained, showing this is correct as the sum of this series is the mathematical constant *e*.

Although this is numerically beautiful - hidden depths include the fact that the terms are of similar magnitudes and convergence is blisteringly quick, and this answer hopefully debunks the common myth that floating point arithmetic is inherently inaccurate, the disadvantage of this approach is that you need to know the upper limit in advance; i.e. you can't stop when a certain tolerance is reached. I know from experience that you'll need about 20 terms.

Comment: Add a conclusion that links this very good mathematical exploration with an explanation of why the program actually exhibits the asked-about problem, for an upvote!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Dunnit.

Comment: Delicious now :)

Comment: is there any possible way to make it show more digits?

Answer (score 4):

This happens because `1000!` is actually a huge number that is much much bigger than what `int` or even `long long` could handle. Also it is important what exactly happens in the real life when multiplication overflows. Long story short, very soon your `num` would be exactly `0` which might be a bit of a surprise to you (this should happen when `n!` becomes divisible by `2^32`). And then attempt to calculate `1/(num)` fails with an arithmetic error (division by 0).

Hint: actually `1000!` is so huge that no standard type can handle it (and `1/1000!` is small enough to be beyond precision of any standard type). If you really want to calculate the sum precisely enough you will have to use some non-trivial tricks.

Answer (score 2):

1. num shouldn't start with -1
2. 'num' will explode on multiplication
3. float gets you only so far. double is better.

Keep track of inverse factorial. In that case, you can just divide the previous value.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double sum = 1.0;
    int num = 1;
    double inv_fact = 1.0;

    for(int i=1; i<=1000; i++)
    {
      inv_fact = inv_fact / i;
      sum += inv_fact;
    }
    cout<<sum<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Gives:
2.71828

Comment: My code above with :    "cout.precision(15); cout<<sum<<endl;" gives 2.71828182845905 which is same as your answer.

Comment: Ha. Touche. Have an upvote. And now I'll be distracted all afternoon analysing that...

Comment: You weren't, which is remarkable given that I was trolling your answer ;-)